# Loading a composer package into Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

**Solved:**  I've added the php and illuminate/support packages into my package composer.json file and it started working. I've got no idea why though so if someone could explain, I would really appreciate it.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "illuminate/support": "~5.0"
 },
```

I've created a composer package for Laravel 5 which should generate models based on an existing database schema. However i'm unable to load it in.

I add my Command class into the app/Console/Kernel.php

```
'Iber\Generator\Commands\MakeModelsCommand'
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Class Iber\Generator\Commands\MakeModelsCommand does not exist
```

I'm really new to Laravel and I'm not sure why this is happening since composer generates the autoloader file just fine. I've created and added `(into config/app.php)` a Service Provider but that doesn't get resolved either. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the package:

https://github.com/ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator

Comment: did you require it into composer.json file? Also take a look if your package was downloaded into vendor's folder

Comment: I did. Strange thing though, i've added php and illuminate/support packages into my package composer.json and it started to work

Comment: If it has been solved please consider answering your own question or deleting it.

Comment: Have you tried removing the support package from composer.json and then run `composer dumpautoload` followed by `php artisan clear-compiled`? It's possible Laravel did update its meta files because you changed the composer.json. If your package actually requires the support package it's still correct to have it included though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently adding the required attribute with the following packages solved the issue. I'm still not sure why.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "illuminate/support": "~5.0"
 },
```